# I am making an flutter application and when I run my app on device it is showing this error again and again on the loop what should I do?

Tags: flutter

**This is the error**

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1160)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1104)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:337)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:28)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:107)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:738)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:329)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(23630):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

**my flutter doctor output**

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
    10.0.18362.207], locale en-IN)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 
    30.0.2)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    [√] Connected device (1 available)


    • No issues found!
```

**my pubspec.yaml file**

```
     cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
     font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
     firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
     firebase_core: ^0.5.2
     cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
     shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
     firebase_storage: ^5.2.0
     image_picker: ^0.6.7+17
     cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
```

Comment: Could you add flutter doctor output and your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: I have added plz check it